# Preventing autosizing of matrix

Tags: matrices

I found out that the matrices are autosized according to the entries in them.

However, this does not look very neat (well, to me). I want the matrices to be of uniform size, like perhaps matrix `d`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ d = \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
x = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \quad = \begin{bmatrix*}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 &  1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: All three matrices look they have the exact same (vertical) size. What exactly are you trying to fix?

Comment: @Mico, the vertical size is fine. I want to change the horizontal size to be that of matrix d. I don't know if it will look better or worse.

Comment: your example doesn't compile.  in needs `mathtools`, not just `amsmath`, and in the final matrix, the begin is starred and the end isn't.  the only way i can think to modify this is to add phantoms (in rather a lot of places), and it won't look any better -- in my opinion it will look a lot worse.

Comment: Try building your matrices from `\left[` and `\right]` with  `array` or `tabular` environments in between to format the data, and give the array columns a fixed-width format like `p{...}`.

Answer (score 3):

As alephzero suggested in his/her comment you could use an array with fixed-width columns.

To choose the appropriate column width you could use `\settowidth{<your width>}{$<your longest element>$}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=3.0cm, top=3.0cm, bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newlength{\mywid}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{\mywid}<{$}}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Your example as a benchmark:
    \[ d = \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix}
    \quad
    x = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 &  1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} \quad  = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 &  1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{bmatrix} \]
    With \verb|\settowidth{\mywid}{$<put here your longest element>$}| you can set a width to use in an \verb|array| environment:
    \settowidth{\mywid}{$-1$}
    \[ 
    d = \left[\begin{array}{@{}*3P@{}}
    -1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \quad
    x = \left[\begin{array}{@{}*3P@{}}
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right] 
    \quad  
    = \left[\begin{array}{@{}*3P@{}}
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
    \end{array}\right]
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]